# spring security login with query string along with form login

Tags: spring-security

We've an application which performs form login with spring security. But now we wanted to authenticate user from the query string as well.  I tried with custom filter but it didn't solve the purpose.  Can anyone please help me in solving the problem?

Comment: Is there anything special with that query string or are you simply trying to send a GET request to the authentication endpoint?

Comment: It's a simple GET request like application.com/login?username="abc" but at the same time application.com/login should redirect to form login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication via `GET` is disabled in spring security for, well, security reasons. GET-requests (and their parameters) make their way into log files what is a very bad thing for login credentials. They can also be cached in upstream proxies where the logging is totally out of your control. You have been warned, but if you really want to:

You can enable auth via `GET` by setting a property on your loginFilter. Depending on your config style (xml or javaconfig) this will be:

```
<bean id="loginFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
  p:postOnly="false" />
```

or

```
@Bean
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter getLoginFilter() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter loginFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    loginFilter.setPostOnly(false);
    return loginFilter;
}
```